# radio_button selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Using Haml 3.1.4 (Separated Sally)

I am curious as to what I am doing wrong.
Why does this not show the first radio button selected?

btw, at execution, @organization.pdf_size does equal 'letter_size'
I would actually like the radio button selected based on the
@organization.pdf_size, however I am just trying to get a hard
coded selection to work atm. tyfyt

```rb
= form_for [@organization] do |f|

  Select a PDF page size

  = label_tag 'Letter (8.5x11)'

  = f.radio_button :pdf_size, id: 'letter_size', :checked => true

  = label_tag 'Half Legal (8.5x7)'

  = f.radio_button :pdf_size, id: 'half_legal_size'

  = f.submit 'Save', class: 'button'
```

I have also tried other examples I have seen on stackoverflow, in this fashion:

```
 = f.radio_button :pdf_size, id: 'letter_size', :checked => @organization.pdf_size == 'letter_size' ? true : nil
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
= f.radio_button :pdf_size, "value", id: 'letter_size', :checked => true
```

As documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button), the radio button needs a value before the options.

Remember to change `"value"` to something that makes sense for your application.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. You are correct, the input type needs a value. In my case I have changed it to:   = setting.radio_button :pdf_size, "letter_size", id: 'letter_size', checked: true

Comment: Good! Mark this as CORRECT ANSWER so we can help others too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try appending this to your link:

```
input_html: {checked: true}
```

Comment: = setting.radio_button :pdf_size, id: 'letter_size', input_html: {checked: true}  //does not work